# Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (or Langevin Monte Carlo) on a Sphere

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I want to perform Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (HMC) or Langevin Monte Carlo (LMC) on a spherical domain $\mathbb{S}^{D-1}$ embedded in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^D$. My energy function is a deep neural network, and its gradient is computed using automatic differentiation.

I have looked up a few materials.

- [Brubaker et al., AISTATS 2012](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v22/brubaker12.html) seems to tackle my problem, but their proposed algorithm using RATTLE, an integrator that involves nonlinear optimization. Solving such optimization is not tractable in my case.
- [Lan et al., ICML 2014](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/lan14.html) also addresses MCMC on a spherical domain, as a part of another problem. Their algorithm seems to work in the spherical coordinate rather than the Euclidean coordinate.

Can I perform LMC on a sphere in a simpler manner?

For example, I want to

- a) use Euclidean coordinates without transformation to spherical coordinate
- b) exploit the simple projection operation onto a sphere, i.e., $x\leftarrow x/||x||$.

In my preliminary experiment, simply projecting samples from each LMC step onto a sphere seems to work. It is not very clear how to perform Metropolis-Hastings adjustment, though.